# The texts lose “quality” after a restoration of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, appearance

I have noticed that after a factory reset on a Windows 10 computer, the texts of the operating system generally "low quality".

The edges of the texts look a bit pixelate... not entirely, but a bit. Before the factory restoration, the texts didn't look like this.

I haven't done too many restorations so far, only two at the moment.

Furthermore, in a previous situation, when I did a clean installation on a PC, not a factory restore, the same thing happened with the borders of the operating system texts.

How could I set it as it was before?

Could it be an Anti-Aliasing theme maybe?

Could it be a Windows 10 version issue? the version I have is `20H2`.

Or a wear on the integrated card? I mention this because in both situations the computer only had an integrated graphics card.

[**Screenshot - "Normal" text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e7xB.png)

[**Screenshot - "Pixelate" text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqAT.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the start menu or the search bar, search for "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows". In the window that opens, select "Adjust for best appearance" and see if it improves. (There is a setting there called "Smooth edges of screen fonts" which may be the culprit if it is not activated.)

Comment: Thanks, but... I haven't made any changes to these options, never. So I have selected by default in the option  `Let Windows choose what's best for my computer`. And in that option, I have all the options selected except: `Save taskbar thumbnail previews` and `Show shadows under mouse pointer`. So the option you mention: `Smooth edges of screen fonts`, I already have it activated by default.